# r shiny hover with multi-panel plots

Tags: r, shiny

Hi I have a shiny app that helps a user visualize electropherograms (essentially spectra) that come from automated DNA sequencers.  I would like the user to be able to hover over a peak and find out the time the peak came off the instrument.  I also would like to be able to compare multiple electropherograms by plotting the spectra one above the other.

If I plot a single spectrum, I can recover the mouse x-position with the 'hover' option provided to plotOutput() in the ui.  If I stack plots using base graphics and the par(mfrow=c(n,1)) where n is the number of spectra, the results are unpredictable.  Basically the x-position is recoverable in part of the plot region but not throughout.

As a final piece of information, I wrote this app several years ago and it's been working as expected until I updated R and the shiny package to fairly recent versions: (R 3.4.4; shiny 1.2.0).

I've included an app.R file that reproduces this issue on a simple case using histograms and the old-faithful data and shows the approach I have been taking.  I get the same behavior whether I set 'clip' in hoverOpts to TRUE or FALSE.

Thanks for any help
allan

```
library(shiny)

ui = fluidPage(

titlePanel("Mulitpanel hover: Old Faithful Geyser Data"),

sidebarLayout(
  sidebarPanel(
     sliderInput("bins","Number of bins:",min = 1,max = 50,value = 30)
  ),

  mainPanel(
     textOutput("xpos"),
     plotOutput("distPlot",hover=hoverOpts(id="plot_hover",clip=TRUE))
      )
   )
 )

 server = function(input, output) {
   output$xpos = renderText({paste("x coord:",input$plot_hover$x)})
   output$distPlot = renderPlot({
   x    = faithful[, 2] 
   bins = seq(min(x), max(x), length.out = input$bins + 1)

   par(mfrow=c(2,1))
   hist(x, breaks = bins, col = 'darkgray', border = 'white')
   hist(x, breaks = bins, col = 'orange', border = 'white')
  })
 }
 shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```